# Choosing the first option in a dynamic select not firing attached event

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a HTML page using Jquery select option as given below..

```
<select id="select-stage" class="spinner" data-inline="true" >
    <option value="-1">-Select Stage-</option>
</select>
```

Now the contents of this select option are give dynamically by an ajax call result.

This is how it looks like

[image]

When I click the `user` option for the first time it is not getting selected. But whereas other options `HOD1`, `HOD2`, `HOD3` etc. are getting selected properly. This only happens for the first time after load. If I select other options and then again select `user` it is getting selected.

It does not get selected only for the first time. I can't spot the problem.

```
var option=[];
$.each(myData, function(key, val) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(trim(val),trim(key));
    option.push('<option value="' + trim(key) + '">' + trim(val) + '</option>');
});
$('#select-stage').html(option.join(''));
}

//changing values on user selection//
$('#select-stage').live('change',function(){
    stageId = sessionStorage.getItem($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    selecttext = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    noselection = true;
    listStageselectedIndexChanged(selecttext);
});
```

Comment: You will probably need to implement a custom widget. The behavior you seem to try to achieve will be unreliable across browsers if you use the standard select input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are replacing the first item in the `select` - which is already selected, therefore the change event is never fired.

You need to keep the `-Select Stage-` option in there as the default and append the new options beneath it. Then when any other option is selected, the `change` event will be fired.

*UPDATE*

To achieve this modify your code to prepend the default option, like this:

```
var option=[];
$.each(myData, function(key, val) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(trim(val),trim(key));
    option.push('<option value="' + trim(key) + '">' + trim(val) + '</option>');
});
$('#select-stage')
    .html(option.join(''))
    .prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Stage-</option>')
    .val('-1');
```

Comment: How do i keep the -Select Stage- option as default ??

Comment: If you edit your question to include the code you have for getting/setting the options, I can show you.

Comment: The values come from a WCF service that is called by ajax and received as JSON objects-(key,value) pairs..

Comment: well this has allowed me to select the USER option..but that doesnt still solve my problem buddy !! Now if i select the -Select Stage- option no effects take place !!!!

Comment: What i need to know is why the first option deosnot get selected for the first time ???

Comment: But anyways i have got my need...thanks 4 that !! but the task of selecting the first option remains unanswered !!

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using your logic and here's my code snippet:     
 var defaultOption;
 defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
 defaultOption.value = "Select A Player";  // assumes option string and value are the same
 defaultOption.text="Select A Player";
 cSelect.add(defaultOption);